# Why PyCharm shows lint error "too few arguments for format string" for mixed keyword and position placeholder?

Tags: python, pycharm, pep

Consider the following code:

```
s = 'ab{}cd{mykey}ef{}gh'.format('01', '23', mykey='45')
print(s)
```

There are 3 placeholders: two positional and one keyword. I've provided enough arguments and the script runs normally, producing the following output:

```
ab01cd45ef23gh
```

But PyCharm warns me the following:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why PyCharm warns that?
2. Should I disable that warning, and how?
3. Or, maybe this kind of code (mixed positional and keyword placeholder) is deprecated by Python? Any document says that?

I'm using PyCharm Community 2018.1 EAP and Python 3.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your PyCharm (2020.1.3 is the latest at the moment).
This is an IDE bug, and it was already fixed since 2018.

Comment: Nope, it is not, error persist in 2023.1.3CE in case of mixing f-string and format smth like `f"{{:.{decimal_digits}f}}".format(value)`. Latest releases have a lot of issues around static checks, `dict have no __get__ method` is another example

Comment: @ArtemBaskakov You have a different issue, caused by mixing f-strings with format, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28089